# iOS AudioStreamer - music not playing in full length

Tags: ios, audiostreamer

In recent work, I am using Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer ( [downloaded from here](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) ) codes to make a music player in my App.

I have an XML file in my remote server I have hosted. This XML file has song title and songs' URL. My App gets the songs' title and URL and using Matt's AudioStreamer, it plays those songs but the problem is the song does not play in full length. Between 30 second to 1 minute, it stops playing and displays "no audio data found" pop up message.

Has anyone used Matt's API for audio stream (I am using here .mp3 files)? 
Can anyone help me to fix this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a corrupt MP3 file - can you provide a link to the MP3 for me to test?  I've written a more advanced AudioPlayer inspired by Matt's AudioStreamer (hosted here: https://code.google.com/p/audjustable/).  I'd be interested in testing it against your files.

Comment: Hi Thong, thanks for the reply. Here is a sample link for an .mp3 file. You can test it. http://andrey.makhonin.ru/music/Irene_Cara_-_Flashdance_What_A_Feeling.mp3

However, I fixed the issue by myself and I uploaded my App to the store. Now I am waiting for the approval :-)

Comment: Hii jeewan i am using same Matt's Audio streamer for playing mp3 songs from urls.Could you please tell me how can you get the end notification of song playing completed.Thanks in advance.